# function returns non-null value, but when assigned it is null

Tags: c#, unity-container, nullreferenceexception

In this line

```
var factory = _compositionRoot.Resolve(desiredType)
                    as IItemLocatorFactory<IMyEntity, ILocatorViewModelItem<IMyEntity>>;
```

I pass a `desiredType` to the following method which resolves it using Unity:

```
public object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        var result = _container.Resolve(type);
                return result;
    }
```

The `result` in the callee is not null. But the `factory` in the caller is null after assignment, and a `NullReferenceException` gets thrown. I am not using any `async` methods. 
`_compositionRoot` is a public class declared in same assembly.

Why am I losing the return value?

EDIT it may be relevant that I have this line in the CompositionRoot class:

```
_container.RegisterInstance<ICompositionRoot>(this);
```

to always return the same instance of the `ICompositionRoot`, i.e. this instance of the public `CompositionRoot` class.

Comment: You're casting with `as` - are you casting to the right type?

Comment: Thanks RobH, I was trying to cast to wrong type (generic covariance/contravariance problem ...)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `as` keyword, [which will return `null` on failure.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) Fix the type cast you are using and it'll work.